# Kendo Panelbar Error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I think i've found a problem with kendo panelbar.

In my project i have a kendo panelbar and sometimes i need all items to be disabled.

The problem is that when all items are disabled and you click anywhere inside the panelbar it raises a javascript error. If you click outside and inside again it raises another. I performed some testes and i guess it may be something related to the fact that kendo panelbar try to put focus in the first enabled item whenever you click in a disabled item.

I thought it was something related to the scripts i have in my project, but i found that this error also occurs in the official telerik panelbar example, but you have to open console in developer tools to see the error because the example runs in a frame of the telerik dojo. You can try it. The link is http://dojo.telerik.com/aXoni

I tried google but didn't find anyone with this problem.

I think its strange no one ever found this bug. Am i doing something wrong or is this really a bug in the telerik panelbar and i have to live with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely seems like a bug so I went ahead and reported it: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/307

In the meantime, you can hack around the problem with a `mousedown` listener during the capture phase: http://dojo.telerik.com/@tjvantoll/OdIj. It's a bit ugly but it'll avoid the error.